# Can I pass the type of an object as a parameter to a method?

Tags: ruby

I have the following methods:

```
ensure_properties_string([:type, :owner, payload)
ensure_properties_boolean([:isOn], payload)
ensure_properties_array([:storage], payload)
ensure_properties_hash([:metadata, :tester], payload)
```

Within each method, I just check if it exists in the payload and is of the type. For example:

```
def ensure_properties_string(properties, hash)
  properties.each do |property|
    unless hash.key?(property.to_s)
      raise_error("#{property} is missing")
    end
    unless property.instance_of? String
      raise_error("#{property} not a string")
    end
  end
```

I want to avoid having so many very similar looking methods. Any ideas how I can reduce them to one method?

Maybe a third string parameter representing type, e.g. `array` could be used along with `case` construction.

Comment: Yep, you can just add a class parameter and pass it. But the question is why do you care about the class exactly rather than the duck type?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean, but I need to raise an error as soon as possible i.e. not to process any further.

Comment: My question was why do you care that something is a `Hash` exactly, rather than that it's indexable for example?

Comment: *It looks like you're trying to write Java in Ruby*

Comment: Where does `payload` come from and why do you need to check its properties? Is this a JSON structure?

Comment: Your method example is invalid.

Comment: Re your just-deleted question: Depending on why you want to do it, doing something when the `index` in the callback is the last index (`results.length - 1`) may be wrong. Remember that ajax is **asynchronous**, and responses can take varying lengths of time, so the last one can finish while one of the previous ones is still running. So **if** your reason is that you want to do something when all is done, don't do that, use `$.when` (or in modern environments, `Promise.all`) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the classes:

```rb
def ensure_properties_of_type(type, properties, hash)
   properties.each do |property|
     raise_error("#{property} is missing") unless hash.key?(property.to_s)
     raise_error("#{property} not a string") unless hash[property.to_s].instance_of? type
   end
end

ensure_properties_of_type(String, [:type, :owner], payload)
ensure_properties_of_type(Array, [:storage], payload)
ensure_properties_of_type(Hash, [:metadata, :tester], payload)
```

Or you can define the methods dynamically:

```rb
[String, Array, Hash].each do |type|
  define_method("ensure_properties_#{type.name.downcase}") do |properties, hash|
    properties.each do |property|
      raise_error("#{property} is missing") unless hash.key?(property.to_s)
      raise_error("#{property} not a string") unless hash[property.to_s].instance_of? type
   end
  end
end

ensure_properties_string([:type, :owner], payload)
ensure_properties_array([:storage], payload)
ensure_properties_hash([:metadata, :tester], payload)
```

Note that there is no `Boolean` class in Ruby.

Comment: Nice  - I presume I can use `raise_error("#{property} not of #{type}")`

Comment: @userMod2 yep, it's visible in that scope with both implementations.

Comment: You left out `isOn` from the example. How would you check for a boolean?

Comment: @Stefan, as I said there is no `Boolean` class in Ruby. I would use `ensure_properties_of_type(TrueClass, [:isOn], payload) || ensure_properties_of_type(FalseClass, [:isOn], payload)` with the first implementation or explicitly define such method with the second implementation.

Comment: `ensure_properties_of_type(TrueClass, [:isOn], payload)` would already raise an error if `isOn` is `false`

Comment: @Stefan right, I would then just define the method explicitly. As for the indexing - I just copy-pasted OP's implementation. I will fix that.